# How does RPC transfer big binary data?

Tags: components, rpc, distributed

If I want to transfer data using RPC or component technology, but the size of data can be very big, how deal with this situation ?
for example, I want to transfer a file to remote as a parameter, but I don't want put the whole file into memory for transferring . How should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's me answer my question.

The answer is [MTOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Transmission_Optimization_Mechanism), make sure the framework you are using support it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider the file transfer solution, smth like establishing FTP connection in the background and make operations supposed to perform on this file data to wait until file transferring completes. Also you should take care of correctness of transferred data, checksumming for instance. The other solution probably is mounting remote directory containing files as a local volume or even setting up a distributed file system if you have all files in one place and you are powered with Linux.